# How to remove modal-open class in Angular on new url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal in which there is a button upon clicking it will route the component (where the modal is present) to another component(questions). The problem is occuring when the new component is loaded the `modal-open` class still remains in `body` tag. Is there any way to remove the `modal-body` ? Also if I click back to previous page the class still remains there.

**modal code**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn login-btn" [disabled]="profileForm.invalid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#instructions">
<div class="modal fade" id="instructions" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Instructions</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                content written here
                <form action="">
                    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-auto my-1">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlAutosizing">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlAutosizing">
                                    To start, click the "Start" button. When finished, click the "Submit Quiz" button.
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto my-1">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/questions']">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have written this css to override the main css but didn't worked:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
    transform: translate(0, -25%);
  }
```

Also I tried to remove the `fade` class from the `modal` div.

Comment: can u put some code also? which library do u use for modal. what is your call function when click the button pu some code please

Comment: @Çağrı i've redited now you can see

Answer (score 0):

in css put

```
.hide{
  display:none !important;
}
```

In your modal read display parameter

```
<div class="modal fade {{display}}" id="instructions" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

then give a click event to your button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"(click)="goToQuestion()">Submit</button>
```

and in component import router

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

in costrunctor put router and create display parameter

```
display="";

constructor(private _router: Router) { }
```

and then write function

```
goToQuestion(){
   //here dismiss modal first then route
    this.display="none";
    this._router.navigate(['questions']);
}
```

Comment: can you please tell how I can dismiss the modal ?

Comment: ```$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```
will this work ?

Comment: this is javascript code in angular if u didn't integrate it to project it will not work.  but u should try ```$("#instructions").hide();``` if it doesn't work then we will try another way

Comment: i also tried ```$("#instructions").removeClass('modal-open');```

Comment: there's no error in console !! What I am seeing is that upon clearing all the css properties of ```modal-backdrop``` the problem is not occuring. I am set all to null in the questions component css and set them to important but nothing is changing

Comment: nope still same and one more thing the question component has one method which sets the component to become is it making any problem ?(upon pressing Esc nothing changes)

Comment: is there any way to make the question component think that it's refreshing itself while in 1st load but in actual it will not refresh ? cz what i've seen upon refreshing the component url the overlay is gone !!

Comment: hi, just to inform you i've just fixed the problem by changing the css properties of ```modal-backdrop``` class in the main style.css file and is working perfectly fine.

And much thanks to you for helping learn something extra :)

Answer (score 0):

In you submit button have data-dismiss="modal" and that should take care of the back drop